# how to remove multiple selected items from a recycler view?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

i want to remove multiple items together from recycler view on one click (delete button) the issue is when i am trying to delete multiple selecting items it is only deselcting the items not deleting all from recycler view

this is my custom adapter class code
package com.example.androidpractice

public class RecyclerUserContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerUserContactAdapter.viewHolder> {

```
Set<Integer> selectedItems = new HashSet<>();
private ImageView imageviewselect;

ImageView imageView;
ImageView imageView1;
TextView textVieww;
Toolbar mainToolbar;
Button button;
public int lastPosition = -1;
Context context;
static ArrayList<userContact_model> modelArray;
TextView textView;
RelativeLayout rootLayout;

RecyclerUserContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<userContact_model> modelArrayListtt, Toolbar mainToolbar) {
    this.context = context;
    this.modelArray = modelArrayListtt;
    this.mainToolbar = mainToolbar;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemview = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contactlist_row, parent, false);
    return new viewHolder(itemview);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {

    holder.itemView.setActivated(selectedItems.contains(position));
    holder.cardView.setActivated(modelArray.get(position).isSelected());

    holder.imageView.setImageResource(modelArray.get(position).image);
    holder.textView.setText(modelArray.get(position).name);
    holder.textView1.setText(modelArray.get(position).number);
    animation(holder.itemView, position);

    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.TransparentDialog);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_add_update);

        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        if (window != null) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            layoutParams.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
            layoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            window.setAttributes(layoutParams);
        }
        textView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.textheading);
        textView.setText(R.string.update_contact);
        button = dialog.findViewById(R.id.add);
        button.setText(R.string.update);

        EditText editText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.namenew);
        EditText editText1 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.numbernew);
        editText.setText(modelArray.get(position).name);
        editText1.setText(modelArray.get(position).number);

        button.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
            String name, number;
            name = editText.getText().toString();
            number = editText1.getText().toString();
            if (!name.equals("") && !number.equals("")) {
                modelArray.set(position, new userContact_model(modelArray.get(position).image, name, number));
                RecyclerUserContactAdapter.this.notifyItemChanged(position);
                dialog.dismiss();
                customtoastupdate();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "please enter the required fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    });

}

public void clearSelections() {
    for (userContact_model model : modelArray) {
        model.setSelected(false);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modelArray.size();
}

public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView imageviewselect;
    TextView textView;
    TextView textView1;
    ImageView imageView;
    CardView cardView;

    public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemview) {
        super(itemview);
        imageView = itemview.findViewById(R.id.image);
        textView = itemview.findViewById(R.id.name);
        textView1 = itemview.findViewById(R.id.number);
        cardView = itemview.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
        imageviewselect = itemview.findViewById(R.id.selecteditem);
        imageviewselect.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        cardView.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                toggleSelection(position);
                customToolbar(position);
                deleteList();
            }
            return true;
        });
    }

    private void toggleSelection(int position) {
        if (selectedItems.contains(position)) {
            selectedItems.remove(position);
        } else {
            selectedItems.add(position);
        }
        modelArray.get(position).setSelected(!modelArray.get(position).isSelected());
        imageviewselect.setVisibility(modelArray.get(position).isSelected() ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

public void animation(View view, int position) {
    if (position > lastPosition) {
        Animation slideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        view.startAnimation(slideIn);
        lastPosition = position;
    }
}

private void customtoastupdate() {
    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View toastview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, (ViewGroup) null);
    TextView textView1 = toastview.findViewById(R.id.toasttext);
    textView1.setText(R.string.updated);
    ImageView imageView = toastview.findViewById(R.id.toastimage);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.updated);
    toast.setView(toastview);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}

private void customtoastdelete() {
    Toast toast = new Toast(context.getApplicationContext());
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View toastview1 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, null);
    TextView textView1 = toastview1.findViewById(R.id.toasttext);
    textView1.setText(R.string.deleted);
    ImageView imageView = toastview1.findViewById(R.id.toastimage);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.deleted);
    toast.setView(toastview1);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}

public void customToolbar(int position) {
    imageView = mainToolbar.findViewById(R.id.search);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.deleted);
    imageView1 = mainToolbar.findViewById(R.id.camera);
    imageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    textVieww = mainToolbar.findViewById(R.id.contactlist);
    textVieww.setTextSize(15);
}

public void deleteList() {
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alertDialog.setTitle("Delete this contact?");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure, you want to delete");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Delete contact", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    List<Integer> selectedItemsList = new ArrayList<>(selectedItems);

                    // Iterate over selectedItemsList in reverse order to avoid index issues
                    for (int i = 0; i <= selectedItemsList.size() - 1; i++) {
                        int position = selectedItemsList.get(i);
                        if (position < modelArray.size()) {
                            modelArray.remove(position);
                        }
                    }
                    // Clear the selectedItems list after removal
                    clearSelections();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    clearSelections();
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

public void deleteSelectedContacts() {
ArrayList<userContact_model> selectedContacts = new ArrayList<>();

```
    for (Integer position : selectedItems) {
        if (position < modelArray.size()) {
            selectedContacts.add(modelArray.get(position));
        }
    }

    modelArray.removeAll(selectedContacts);
    clearSelections();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Can you post your recyclerview adapter's code. It's not clear whether you are modifying the list used to compute the size of the list and to bind the view holders.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.